# How to get facebook friends work_history and company id?

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql, facebook-friends

Hi I am using following FQL to fetch friends list from facebook and their details

> select uid, name, work_history,
>   education_history, current_location
>   from user where uid IN  (select uid2
>   from friend where uid1=FACEBOOK_USER);

and I get the following result array which fine and correct.

Now my question is it any how possible to get the company id in which friend works. A unique identifier of the company so that I can fetch company specific details using e.g. 
 http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola   (an example of getting details of cocacola company/fan-page)  ???

Such as friend working in GO-AdventureSports should also have unique identifier in the array.

> Array
>   (
>       [0] => Array
>           (
>               [uid] => 12312312312
>               [name] => Raj Singh
>               [work_history] => Array
>                   (
>                       [0] => Array
>                           (
>                               [company_name] => Intersil
>                           )

```
            )

        [education_history] => Array
            (
            )

        [current_location] => Array
            (
                [city] => Santa Clara
                [state] => California
                [country] => United States
                [zip] => 
                [id] => 1231231231
                [name] => Santa Clara, California
            )

    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [uid] => 123123123
        [name] => Rana Sidhu
        [work_history] => Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [location] => Array
                            (
                                [city] => 
                                [state] => 
                            )

                        [company_name] => GO-AdventureSports
                        [description] => 
                        [start_date] => 
                        [end_date] => 
                    )

            )

        [education_history] => Array
            (
            )

        [current_location] => 
    )
```

Any ideas are highly appreciated ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the above sql query just add **work** and it will return company names with their ids. Now if one want **work_history** can be ignored.

final query

> select uid, name, work_history, work,
>   education_history, current_location
>   from user where uid IN (select uid2
>   from friend where uid1=FACEBOOK_USER);

Hope it help some one.

-deepak

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

> select uid, name,work, work_history, education_history,
>   current_location from user  where uid IN (select uid2 from friend
>   where uid1=FACEBOOK_USER);

work gives company name with it's id on facebook and work_history doesn't give id's only give plain information.

See following output:

```
[work] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [employer] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 105551752814478
                                    [name] => Fujitsu Consulting India Ltd
                                )

                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 106442706060302
                                    [name] => Pune, Maharashtra
                                )

                            [position] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 139966739368093
                                    [name] => IT Consultant
                                )

                            [start_date] => 2009-10
                            [end_date] => 0000-00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [employer] => Array
                                (
                                    [id] => 109256905760858
                                    [name] => Fujitsu
                                )

                        )

                )

            [work_history] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [city] => Pune
                                    [state] => Maharashtra
                                )

                            [company_name] => Fujitsu Consulting India Ltd
                            [position] => IT Consultant
                            [description] => 
                            [start_date] => 2009-10
                            [end_date] => 0000-00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [location] => Array
                                (
                                    [city] => 
                                    [state] => 
                                )

                            [company_name] => Fujitsu
                            [description] => 
                            [start_date] => 
                            [end_date] => 
                        )

                )
```